# There is no way for me to boot recovery mode on my tablet

Tags: adb, rooting, recovery-mode, 9.0-pie

So, I recently thought about rooting my Lenovo Tab M10 (according to the TWRP site, TB-X605F), so I flashed the latest version of TWRP to my tablet from fastboot, and realised: "Oh. I can't boot recovery on this." Holding power+volume down brings me to fastboot again, as expected. Power+volume up shows a weird "FFBM Mode" message in what looks to be the Arial font, centred on screen, on a grey background. Holding power and both volume buttons boots as if i was just holding power. I have no idea what to do. None of the `fastboot boot` commands exist on my tablet, nor do some of the `fastboot oem` commands. I am running Android 9.0 Pie on my tablet, and Linux Mint on my PC, using the `adb` and `fastboot` packages if that would help.

UPDATE: I managed to (accidentally) find out that if I boot to android, then hold power, volume up, and volume down at the same time until it turns off, then release power as the Lenovo logo appears, I can boot the stock recovery. However, I need to flash TWRP, and then boot it before booting android so it doesn't get overwritten. I still have no answers, but at least I know I **can** actually boot recovery mode.

Comment: So you have enabled OEM unlock in Android Settings and unlocked bootloader?

Comment: that's strange because [Vol Up](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/lenovo/lenovo-tab-m10/recovery-mode) *should* work. try again with/without usb cable. if no success you are left with rooting via [official](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/README.MD#downloads) method and *'reboot recovery'* from adb or terminal (with root)

Comment: I've always managed to boot into recovery by pressing PowerButton+VolUp+VolDown until the phone boots up. It usually enters recovery after that. I have tried this on another lenovo device I have codenamed a6020a46.

Comment: @alecxs still doesn't work, weird

Comment: @Robert i have, and i can't re-lock it from the developer settings for some reason

Comment: @linux_enthusiast oh, i forgot to add that doing this just boots normally, i'll add that in the post 
(edit: i didn't forget, oops)